# showing $k[x,y]\ncong k[u,v,w]/(uw-v^2)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $k$ be a field. I want to show that $k[x,y]\ncong k[u,v,w]/(uw-v^2)$ as $k$-algebras, but can't find a way to do it.

The dimension of the $k$-vector space generated by the degree 1 monomials are different on both sides, but then it's possible that an isomorphism doesn't preserve the graded parts, right?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint; $k[x,y]$ is a unique factorization domain but $k[u,v,w]/(uw-v^2)$ is not a UFD, since $[v]^2=[u][w]=[v][v].$